# How to avoid connection loopbacks with DynDNS when I debug locally?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, oauth, dns, jetty

I'm developing with Java GAE and Google API's with OAuth authentication that requires an URL Callback that receives the access tokens.

To test locally, running Jetty in 127.0.0.1:8888/home.html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997, I've configure a DynDNS domain and set my router to redirect traffic from port 8888 to my machine.

When I do that DynDNS domain shows my router web configuration page, like I was browsing to my router local IP.

I've achieved a workaround activating my StrongVPN account to trick the router loopback, but when DynDNS refresh the VPN IP I can't access anymore, well I have to wait a lot of time to do the trick again.

How can I avoid these loopback connections? Should I set up a proxy? Anyone has met this scenario (local debug GAE+G.APIs+OAuth)?

**Edit:**

I'll show you my LAN configuration (trying to discard causes):

---

INTERNET (WAN IP) <-> ISP Router (192.168.1.1) <-> (192.168.1.2) Neutral Router (192.168.0.1) <-> (192.168.0.XX manual static IP) MacBook Local Server

I set this port forwarding configuration in my ISP Router to redirect the incoming port 80 connections to my 8888 port
 - TCP port 80 to 192.168.1.2 port 8888

I set this port forwarding configuration in my Neutral Router
 - Port 8888 to 192.168.0.XX

The configuration described would be OK because if I access through my mobile 3G connection to mydyndns.dyndns.org I access to Eclipse local web server.

---

Then, I tried to edit host file as Owen *"point your DynDNS domain to 127.0.0.1"* says but without success :(

If I set '127.0.0.1 mydyndns.dyndns.org' in my hosts file dyndns domain doesn't work, I think is because port forwarding, but I receive a not found, as if I type 127.0.0.1 in the browser. Eclipse server is attaching 127.0.0.1:8888 then port 80 doesn't have nothing to show.

If I set '127.0.0.1:8888 mydyndns.dyndns.org' in my hosts file I access to the ISP Router web configuration page as I was typing 192.168.1.1. But the address is inmediately replaced on the browser address bar for MY_WAN_IP:80

Then I think that a connection loopback is happening. Any idea about how to fix that :(?

Answer (score 2):

You could edit the hosts file on your machine to point your DynDNS domain to 127.0.0.1  That's what I do.

The location of the hosts file depends on your operating system.  Check the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_%28file%29) to find it's location in your OS and how to edit it.

In addition to editing your hosts file, I think you can follow the advice in this question/answer to locally forward.  https://serverfault.com/questions/102416/iptables-equivalent-for-mac-os-x

Comment: Thanks Owen but I can't fix the problem, I edit my question with more info about my scenario, if there are any information that do you think would be useful ask me :)

Comment: Updated with a link to a question on serverfault that might point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I change my ADSL Provider and the main router, with that I reconfigure the scenario as the documents says and it works.

I'm sorry for so specific question, that was a ISP problem who, for any reason, don't support or has any undocumented custom configuration to configure your own server.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this problem by connecting to my ADSL Router via Telnet (the command after you're in telnet is "o router-web-configuration-ip-here") and then I issued the commands to check NAT loopback ("ip nat l"), after verifying it was off I issued the command to turn it on ("ip nat l on"). You can also edit the autoexec.net ("sys edit autoexec.net", "n" [twice], "ip nat l on", "x" ) of the router to make the change permanent.

I also did edit the HOSTS in my machine, placing my server's own local IP tied to the DynDNS host.

I'm using Windows 7 for development, I don't know about your specific configuration, but this might help others doing SO/HO dev.